# Can I use Google Maps Drive mode without entering a destination and still have it control texts and music?

Tags: sms, google-maps, music-player, hands-free

I have a Pixel 4XL on Android 12. I would like to get in my car and have one app that controls my hands-free texting and music like Android Auto used to. Google Maps navigation mode has the ability to do this, but only when I enter a destination. With a destination, it is great. Exactly what I need. But unless I enter my destination every single time, it doesn't work safely.

I am aware that I can put a widget that enters drive/navigation mode when pressed and have added that widget. However, it still requires me to enter a destination before it will control text and music. If I simply leave it w/o a destination there is text control but no music control.

Is there a way for Maps-Driving mode to show me my map, have the music control at the bottom, and control texting without having to enter a destination every single time?

Comment: I don't think this is truly possible with the current version of this feature (as of 5/2/23). You can enter driving mode using the "I'm driving" Assistant command or the "Driving" widget from Google Maps. While you can have the Assistant-enabled voice control features without entering a destination, it appears music controls, at the very least, are inaccessible until you choose a destination.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze)

See Screen below

[image]

- The destination is not required.
- It uses Google Assistant, so you can use it to call, send sms or speak your destination.
- You can link in one audio player, its available through the note symbol
- The map is updatable by the community, so is current
- So are traffic conditions such as potholes, accidents, cops.